# connecting SchemaSpy to Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine fails with Connection Failure

Tags: sql-server, docker, schemaspy

I am running my database locally in [Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) I can successfully connect to it using `mssql-cli -U username -P password -d dbname` however I am struggling to connect to it using SchemaSpy e.g.

```
$ java -jar schemaspy-6.0.0.jar -t mssql -u username -p password -o . -host localhost -port 1433 -db dbname
INFO  - Started Main in 1.183 seconds (JVM running for 1.556)
INFO  - Configuration file not found
INFO  - Starting schema analysis
INFO  - Failed to validate png renderer ':cairo'.  Reverting to default renderer for png.
WARN  - Connection Failure
```

Any idea what I can do to fix the Connection Failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started SQL server with this:

```
docker run --name sqlserver -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=BadPassword1' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

I'd check that you've given your Docker Desktop enough RAM. When I first started SQL Server with Docker configured for < 2GB RAM, the container started, but I couldn't connect, when I looked in the logs:

```
docker logs sqlserver
```

(sqlserver is the name of the exited Docker container)

I saw:

```
sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.
```

Once I'd updated my Docker Desktop to have 2GB of RAM again (I'd dropped it to 1GB a while ago), it came up fine.

One that was up, I could use `nmap localhost -p 1433` to validate that the port was open.

I then checked that SQL Server was up-and-running by starting an interactive shell on the running container:

```
docker exec -it --rm sqlserver /bin/bash
```

Inside the interactive shell I could use `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P BadPassword1` to access the SQL server shell. In the mssql shell you have to type what you want, then input `GO` on its own line to execute everything you've entered.

So, to list the dbs:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases;
GO
```

To list the tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES;
GO
```

I then created a DB and a table to run SchemaSpy against:

```
CREATE DATABASE SchemaSpyTest;
GO;
USE SchemaSpyTest;
GO;
CREATE TABLE TableTest1(id int);
GO
```

Then, I ran the parameters you listed on SchemaSpy and it didn't work for me either.

Once I'd used the -debug flag, I saw that the `mssql` setting wasn't enough:

```
org.schemaspy.model.ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to database URL [jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname] Failed to create any of 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver' driver from driverPath 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/msbase.jar;C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/mssqlserver.jar;C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/msutil.jar' with sibling jars no.
Resulting in classpath: empty
There were missing paths in driverPath:
        C
        /Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/msbase.jar;C
        /Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/mssqlserver.jar;C
        /Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC/lib/msutil.jar
Use commandline option '-dp' to specify driver location.
If you need to load sibling jars used '-loadjars'
        at org.schemaspy.DbDriverLoader.getConnection(DbDriverLoader.java:101)
        at org.schemaspy.DbDriverLoader.getConnection(DbDriverLoader.java:75)
        at org.schemaspy.service.SqlService.connect(SqlService.java:68)
        at org.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.analyze(SchemaAnalyzer.java:186)
        at org.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.analyze(SchemaAnalyzer.java:107)
        at org.schemaspy.cli.SchemaSpyRunner.runAnalyzer(SchemaSpyRunner.java:97)
        at org.schemaspy.cli.SchemaSpyRunner.run(SchemaSpyRunner.java:86)
        at org.schemaspy.Main.main(Main.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

So, I downloaded the JDBC driver from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57782 and unarchived it in the same folder as my other scripts.

I was then able to work out the right combination of parameters based on the docs:

```
java -jar schemaspy-6.0.0.jar -t mssql05 -u sa -p BadPassword1 -o . -host localhost -port 1433 -db SchemaSpyTest -debug -dp ./sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar
```

The dp flag links to the JAR file within the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.

After that, it worked perfectly.